# how to block cross frame scripting in Apache for svn

Tags: apache, svn, xss, mod-security2

I have SVN configured thru Apache 2.4.18 on Linux 6.6. Next i have to disable cross frame scripting for my svn url. SVN url is like https://servername/svn/projectA. I have compiled mod_security2.so and copied to /modules directory and loaded then in virtualHost have the lines below.

```
LoadFile /usr/lib64/libxml2.so
LoadFile /usr/lib64/liblua-5.1.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so

    httpd-vhosts.conf 
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/local/apache/httpd2.4.18/htdocs"
    ServerName servername.fqdn.com
    # For http to https redirect    
    Redirect / https://servername
    TraceEnable off
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    SecRuleEngine On 
    #SecFilterEngine On
    #SecFilterForceByteRange 32 126
    #SecFilterScanPOST On
    #SecFilter "<( |\n)*script"
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecResponseBodyAccess On
    ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The rules that Apache not supported are

> SecFilterEngine
>   SecFilterForceByteRange
>   SecFilterScanPOST
>   SecFilter
>   Blockquote

Instead of SecFilterEngine, its taking SecRuleEngine. But I do not know alternative rule for other rules. I am using modsecurity-2.9.0 source compiled. The error i see is below. [root@server extra]# /var/local/apache/httpd2.4.18/bin/apachectl configtest
AH00526: Syntax error on line 45 of /var/local/apache/httpd2.4.18/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
Invalid command 'SecFilterForceByteRange', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. Any one know the mod_security2 supported modules for SecFilterForceByteRange, SecFilterScanPOST and SecFilter. I also read documentation about mod_security but could not figure out and solve the issue. I followed the url below.

> http://www.unixpearls.com/how-to-block-xss-vulnerability-cross-site-scripting-in-apache-2-2-x/

[EDIT]
Its solved by adding the header response.

Comment: You can accomplished this only configuring mod_headers https://www.namhuy.net/3154/secure-apache-http-web-server.html

Comment: @Joao - In the response headers, I see X-Frame-Options as SAMEORIGIN. Is this the right one. do you know the options to test this functionality in apache commandline. I think you fixed this.

Comment: See if this help https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Clickjacking_(OTG-CLIENT-009)

Comment: Got to understand x-frame options. This is new for me. It good one.

Answer (score 0):

All those unsupported commands are ModSecurity v1 commands and have been completely rewritten for ModSecurity2.

The rule you would want would be something like this:

```
SecRule ARGS "<( |\n)*script" "phase:2,id:1234,deny"
```

This basically scans any of your arguments (as parameters or the body) for items like this:

```
<script
```

or

```
< script
```

or

```
<
script
```

That's not a bad start to trying to protect for XSS but is a bit basic.

OWASP has a Core Rule Set of ModSecurity rules and their XSS rules are much more complex and can be seen here: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf

XSS can be exploited in a number of ways, some of which will make it to your server (and this sort of thing might catch) and some which might not even make it to your server at all (and so which this can't protect against).

The best way to protect against XSS is to look at Content Security Policy, which allows you to explicitly say what javascript you want to allow on your site, and what not, and to explicitly deny in-line scripts if you want. This may require some clean up of your site to remove inline scripts and is not always the easiest to set up, particularly if loading third party assets and widgets on your site, but is the most robust protection.

The X-Frame-Options header is useful to stop your site being framed, and someone overlaying content to make you think you are clicking on the real site buttons and fields, but actually clicking their buttons. It's not really a form of XSS, since you are more putting scripting on an invisible window on top of your site rather than directly on your site, but can have similar effects. It's a good header to use.